# Why qDebug and QLabel don't show unicode?

Tags: c++, qt, encoding

I have a byteArray with 2 bytes. Those 2 bytes in `UTF-8` mean `"Š"` ( one letter ) and in windows-1250 they mean `"ÂŠ"` ( two letters ), so they are properly in these two encodings.

My code:

```
    QByteArray byteArray;
    byteArray.append(0xC2);
    byteArray.append(0x8A);

    QTextStream textStreamUTF(byteArray);
    textStreamUTF.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
    QString stringUTF = textStreamUTF.readLine();

    QTextStream textStreamAnsi(byteArray);
    textStreamAnsi.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForLocale());
    QString stringAnsi = textStreamAnsi.readLine();

    qDebug()<<stringUTF<<stringAnsi;
```

In debug I see: `"\u008A" "ÂŠ"` , so `stringAnsi` is correctly displayed. StringUTF is properly set ( \u008A is Š ), but it isn't correctly displayed ( I would like to see "Š" ).

The same with QLabels and setText. When I set stringAnsi, I see on the screen good characters. When I set stringUTF I see nothing.

Comment: did you try using tr() ? see [Using tr() for All Literal Text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html)

Comment: `qDebug()<<tr(stringUTF.toUtf8())<<stringAnsi;`

Comment: @Parisa.H.R thank you for answer, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I changed UTF-8 to UTF-16 and stringUTF  correctly displayed but stringAnsi doesn't show and I don't know why .

Comment: are you sure Š is encoded as `{0xC2, 0x8A}` ?
A search online seems to indicate it should be `{0xc5, 0xa0}`

Comment: @Robin Yeah, that was my bad. Thank you :)